How to reduce the CPU consumption's in react bar chart for 34k points?
I have a bar chart using the Recharts library, but I'm struggling to handle 34,000 data points on the x and y axes. My system hangs and I'm unable to render the chart properly.
can you provide the solution so how can i vertualized it
can you please provide the proper logic so i can render the bar chart for large data?.
 <Bar
                  key={key}
                  dataKey={key}
                  shape={<RoundedTopBar />}
                  fill={predefinedColors[index % predefinedColors.length]}
                />
              ))}


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I’ve had this happen with other chart libraries  After realizing that there were so many points that they wouldn’t all be visibly distinguishable, my solution was to preprocess the data to remove points.  You could select every 100th point, for example, and only display the selected points. I don’t know that whether that would make sense given your data and data display needs.
